# Rest controller is not recognizing get request in Spring Boot app on PCF(Pivotal Cloud Foundary)

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have deployed an application in PCF it is running on the local machine but on PCF,

The Rest Controller is not recognizing get a request in Spring Boot app.

`/healthwatch/api/greeting` is my get request

but in logs, it is printing as follows

`/healthwatch/error`

Could you please help me.

`$ cf app health-watch-api`
`Showing health and status for app health-watch-api in org mastercard_connect / space developer-sandbox as e069875...`
`name:              health-watch-api`
`requested state:   started`
`routes:            health-watch-api.apps.stl.pcfdev00.mastercard.int`
`last uploaded:     Fri 05 Oct 12:19:35 IST 2018`
`stack:             cflinuxfs2`

Comment: Post full details of the App in PCF... execute `cf app <app-name>` command and update your post with full details. We will have to know the `route` mapped to the App and all  other information

Comment: @Arun I have given details.

Comment: what happens when you hit `http://health-watch-api.apps.stl.pcfdev00.mastercard.int/healthwatch/api/greeting` .  Show the network-logs that comes in your browser. Also show the way you have configured the routes in your `Spring Boot` App .. Also tell if you have protected your REST Endpoints ?

Comment: I am getting ERROR 500 when i hit that API, And the way of configuring routes means...i didnt understood that.

Comment: Show your Spring Boot code

Comment: Please share your controller implementation.

Comment: A 500 error means that your app is failing. There will be an associated stack trace in your app's logs to show exactly what happened. If you run `cf logs <app>` and then replicate the 500 error, you should see the full stack trace. You can use that to review your code and see why it's failing.